# Github - Set a commit to origin (using Sourcetree)?

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit, sourcetree

I want to set the last commit to the origin. 
(So that my origin is the same as my last commit)

My history looks like this:

[image]

What do I have to do? 
(I'm a github noob..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the 'Push' button to push the commits to your origin.

Alternatively using commandline: git push origin.